# How can I join application data with user information in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am developing my first ever asp.net web application and have run into a problem, which is most certainly related to me being a newbee, but here goes:

I am using Entity Framework 6, mvc 5.1, c#. I have made changes to the user record (ASP.NET Identity) simply by adding a few fields. Now based on a value (OrganizationID) in the user record, I would like to limit data being shown to that of the user's organization. OrganizationID is stored in the Seasons table, but I can't find out why I cannot simply write something along the lines of:
   .include(s => s.OrganizationID == currentUser.OrganizationID)
which is commented out below.

Am I doing this totally wrong? I will be needing this over and over in my application, I believe, so getting it right is crucial for me.

Thanks

(the code below runs fine but of course not constrained to the users organization!)
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {

```
        // my code to get current user record (ASP.NET Identity)
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        // 

        var viewModel = new SeasonGoals();
        viewModel.Seasons = db.Seasons
            .Include(g => g.Goals);
      //    .include(s => s.OrganizationID == currentUser.OrganizationID) 
        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.SeasonID = id.Value;
            viewModel.Goals = viewModel.Seasons.Where(s => s.ID == id.Value).Single().Goals;

        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass foreign key property in include by which these two classes are linked,try like this:

```
viewModel.Seasons = db.Seasons
            .Include("ForeignKeyPropery")
            .Where(s => s.OrganizationID == currentUser.OrganizationID)
```

or you can write like this:

```
(from c in db.Seasons.Include(c => c.Goals)
        where c.OrganizationID == currentUser.OrganizationID
        select c)
```